# Is it possible reposition and resize UIImageView of a standard UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Now I know that the UITableViewCell by default have a imageView however I tried sizing the size of it and the origin, but it won't do it. Do I have to subclass a UITableViewCell just to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to create a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the default style of table view cell, you'd better subclass one, you can change it's image view's frame easily by `layoutSubviews` method, just like this:

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

//...

- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  // ...
  CGRect imageViewFrame = CGRectMake(...);
  [self.imageView setFrame:imageViewFrame];

  // you can also modify the frame or position for textLabel, detailTextLabel, etc.
}

@end
```

Comment: Why can't I change the frame? I wrote code on tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath cell.imageView setframe: do I have to have a custom cell class?

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi i think it'll relayout its frame after you set it before rendering the cell. If you don't want to do subclass, just add a image view like scorpiozj described (but you can imagine that there're two imageViews now, one is just without any image defined). So I prefer customizing one. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to add a `UIImageView` to the `cell.contentview`.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *myImageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 30, 30)];
myImageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[cell.contentView  addSubview:myImageview];
[myImageview release];
```